# increment enum value when button pressed

Tags: c++, c, arduino

I have below function has enum. I wanted to increment the value if button being pressed.

```
typedef enum {
  DATE_TIME,
  COORDINATE,
  WINDSPEED,
  POSITIONTRACK,
  DISPAY_PARAMETER,
  SET_PARAMETER,
  DISPLAY_TYPE_MAX
}DISPLAY_SCREEN_TYPE;
DISPLAY_SCREEN_TYPE display_screen_type=DATE_TIME;

button=check_key();
if(button==RIGHT)
display_screen_type++;
```

error message i am getting while compile.

```
error: no 'operator++(int)' declared for postfix '++', trying prefix operator instead
error: no match for 'operator++' in '++display_screen_type'
```

This my actual code syntax
[CODE discription](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7036971/)

Comment: Sure. Enums aren't types with arithmetic operations defined. You may explicitly cast from/to int, but it's ugly.

Comment: how can declare enum as int with above value

Comment: Maybe you need to build a finite state machine (FSM) to properly handle states of your program and transitions between the states. As @millinon suggests you may use simple `switch` if your program is simple enough, or take a look at one of existing FSM libraries for C++, _for example_ http://boost-extension.redshoelace.com/docs/boost/fsm/doc/state_machine.html

Comment: This works for C, but it does not work for C++.

Comment: i am using it for Switch statement implementation.Assume if button== right pressed twice then it should change enum value update to next.if again pressed change it to next enum value.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Even though an `enum` might be created with ints in the compiler, does it make sense to try to use an increment operator (`++`) on a screen_type variable? What is supposed to happen if the screen type is `DISPLAY_TYPE_MAX` and the right button is pressed?

It's possible to force the compiler to accept your `enum`/`int` conversion, but doing so is going to make the code harder to read.

The purpose of an `enum` is to restrict a variable's values to one contained by the enum. It's almost like making a new variable type, and declaring that the type is restricted to a certain set of values. In this sense, an `enum` isn't really meant to be treated as a mathematical value (like an `int`), so it doesn't really make sense to use `++` on one.

As an alternative, I'd recommend using a `switch` or just writing a function to perform the right button action.

Comment: I have 5 keys: up/down/right/left/select. and menus display and set. these 5 key used to serve different purpose inside loop. @ beginning default display:date and time. if right key pressed change display to coordinate,  if again change enum value. I am using switch key to take action.

Answer (score 0):

Enum value are not suppose to have arithmetic operations. it is a set with limited number of values.

although you can declare enum's underlying type in c11 in to manipulate it. but arduino's avr-compiler may not support it.

you can change enum into a int/byte type, and define enum values as integer value.

```
#define DATE_TIME (0)
// other values. 
int display_type;
```